# UIView width and height reversed

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an iPad app and I'm having an issue in my `rootViewController`. I'm getting the wrong frame for it for some reason.  The rotation works fine visually, but when I'm in landscape mode my width and height are reversed.  Logging the frame I get the following:

Portrait: `self view frame = {{0, 20}, {768, 1004}}`
Landscape: `self view frame = {{20, 0}, {748, 1024}}`

That `20px` for the status bar is moving as it should. But those values should be flipped.  This view has a `UIScrollView` as a subview and it's frame is adjusting as it should.  Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the width and height were reversed, the origin would then be wrong... I think this is the expected behaviour, as these coordinates are in the super view's system. What do you get with the `bounds` rectangle?

Comment: The bounds look right.  What's the origin supposed to be in IB?  Right now I have it on the top left.

Comment: I want to be able to use the center property to center subviews.

Comment: Centre is defined in the superview's coordinate system, so you'd make a point at the centre of your bounds rectangle, and set the centre of your subviews to this.