# UILabel set to center of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel

How come the `UILabel` drawn in this code is not in the center of the `view`?

```
//create the view and make it gray
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

//everything for label
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,42,21)];

//set text of label
NSString *welcomeMessage = [@"Welcome, " stringByAppendingString:@"username"];
welcomeMessage = [welcomeMessage stringByAppendingString:@"!"];
label.text = welcomeMessage;

//set color
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

//properties
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[label sizeToFit];

//add the components to the view
[view addSubview: label];
label.center = view.center;

//show the view
self.view = view;
```

The line, `label.center = view.center;` should move the `label` to the center of the `view`. But instead moves it to where the center of the `label` is in the left hand corner of the `view` as shown below.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/2d1c064a671e32c7eb004647232fa430.png))</sub>

Does anyone know why?

Comment: First of all why you do `self.view=view` ? You don't need that, second  your `view` doesn't have a frame set. Third, use label.center = self.view.center.

Comment: First, because I am building a view within an application. Second, How do I do that. And third, I use `view.center` because I am creating a new view. I need to set the view to `UIView *view` using `self.view= view`

Comment: I suppose that this code is in `-viewDidLoad`. Right?

Comment: For second, alloc/init for the view, view.frame = CGRectMake(...)

Comment: @MohannadA.Hassan Yes, my apologies, should of clarified.

Comment: @danypata Paramaters being, (0,0,320,280)?

Comment: Depends, if you want full screen then should be (0,0,320,480) if not it can be any value.

Comment: I agree with @danypata. You don't need to create a new view. In `viewDidLoad`, it's already created. You can change its `backgroundColor` directly.

Comment: @MohannadA.Hassan This is just a test app for another part of an app I am making, I am just testing components with this view, then I can copy and paste into my other app when I am done.

Comment: @danypata Ah... I thought I remembered 320 x n80 or something like that. Haha.

Comment: You get a view in viewDidLoad: method itself. Just change its various properties for that only. Why create a new view and replacing the old one just for changed properties.

Comment: Yes and thats why I explained too in your last question too. Without a provided frame, a view has CGRectZero frame i.e. (0,0,0,0). So always set a frame for UIViews.

Comment: There is no need to create another view in `viewDidLoad` just to ad a button. See GuillaumeA's answer.

Comment: @ott and see my comment for the explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to init your view with a frame:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by your `view` variable not having a frame defined. By default it has a frame set to `(0, 0, 0, 0)`, so its center is `(0, 0)`.

Hence when you do `label.center = view.center;`, you set the center of your label to `(0 - label.width / 2, 0 - label.height /2)`. `(-80.5 -10.5; 161 21)` in your case.

There is no need for a new `UIView` if your `UIViewController` already have one, just work with `self.view`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //create the view and make it gray
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    //everything for label
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    //set text of label
    // stringWithFormat is useful in this case ;)
    NSString *welcomeMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome, %@!", @"username"];
    label.text = welcomeMessage;

    //set color
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //properties
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [label sizeToFit];

    //add the components to the view
    [self.view addSubview: label];
    label.center = self.view.center;
}
```

Also note that doing `label.center = self.view.center` [will not work properly when rotating to landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180857/landscape-mode-uiview-center-gives-potrait-mode-coordinates).

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work fine if you put it in the viewDiLayoutSubviews instead of viewDidLoad