# UIViewcontroller keeps portrait coordinates when in landscape mode

Tags: uiviewcontroller, coordinates, landscape

I have an app that is designed to start up in Landscape mode, this all works fine.  I add an imageview to cover the screen and then add a scrollview halfway down.  Again all works fine.

I then add a series of uiimageviews again all fine.  I notice if i try to click the far right image there is no response but the other images preceding this work fine.  With lots of digging around I discovered the viewcontroller keep portrait coordinates.  I have a tabbar at the bottom when I click to go to another view and then go back to the main view the far right uiimageview not works.  Has anyone seen this before?  I am guessing the view is redrawing itself when it comes back?

Answer (score 0):

You should use .bounds property instead of the .frame property of the view.
Bounds honor the UIVIew's coordinate system.
It's well explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8181113/402223

Answer (score 0):

See this article which answered my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156979/ios7-setting-selectedindex-of-uitabbarcontroller-breaks-touch-events-along-rig)

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    // fix for iOS7 bug in UITabBarController
    self.selectedViewController.view.superview.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```

note don't add it to viewdidload method.

Thanks Martijn you put me on the right track.